# Priority when more than one element use the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having a problem with jQuery.

I'm doing a mobile menu using jQuery with sub menus.  I need to use the same class to activate all the menus because they will be created dynamically, but when I do this, when I click on a item, all the others show their sub-item too.

To be clear, here's an example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="OpenMenu"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Menu 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-item">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="OpenMenu"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-item">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="OpenMenu"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Menu 3</a>
        <ul class="sub-item">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need each menu to show its sub-items only when is clicked, but all using the same class. I'm doing the "open" effect of the menus with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve by below code, `find()` method will drill down to only its child items and find sub items

```
$(".OpenMenu").click(function(){
$(this).find('.sub-item').show();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lboyrqnc/1/)** (covers only displaying required sub menu)

To view how to hide other sub items and display only current items, use this http://jsfiddle.net/Lboyrqnc/2/

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

And now my jQuery codes will be much more short LOL.

Comment: Most welcome, hopefully link2 might have helped you to hide other sub items.